# Angular dynamically change loaded data

Tags: angularjs

I tried to change my data dynamically without keep requesting to server.

Here is my current code:

```
$scope.total_earned = () => { //ng-click function from frontend
        splice();
        loadChartData(1);
};
$scope.total_cashback = () => { //ng-click function from frontend
    splice();
    loadChartData(2);
};

loadChartData(1);

function splice(){
    $scope.chartConfig.series = [];
}
function loadChartData(type) {
    Vendor.get({id: vendorId}).$promise.then((data) => {
        $scope.datePicker = {startDate: moment(data.metadata.start_date), endDate: moment(data.metadata.end_date)};
        $scope.data = data;
        for (var key in data) {
            var arr = [];
            var arr2 = {};
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (key != 'metadata') {
                    var obj = data[key];
                    $.map(obj, function (el, index) {
                        var date = moment.utc(el.date).valueOf();
                        var value = 0;
                        if (type == 1) {
                            value = el.total_amount;
                        }
                        else if (type == 2) {
                            value = el.total_earned;
                        }
                        else if (type == 3) {
                            value = el.total_spent;
                        }

                        arr.push([date, parseInt(value)]);
                        arr2[key] = arr;
                    });
                    $scope.chartConfig.series.push(
                        {
                            name: key,
                            type: 'line',
                            data: arr2[key],
                            animation: true
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

my json output:

```
{
  "vendor1": [{
      "total_earned": "313028",
      "total_spent": "92231",
      "total_amount": "3222509",
      "date": 1450828800
  }, {
      "total_earned": "281966",
      "total_spent": "87324",
      "total_amount": "2906973",
      "date": 1450915200
  }, {
      "total_earned": "265567",
      "total_spent": "82190",
      "total_amount": "2737860",
      "date": 1451001600
  }],

  "vendor2": [{
      "total_earned": "114122",
      "total_spent": "41223",
      "total_amount": "512123",
      "date": 1450828800
  }, {
      "total_earned": "125613",
      "total_spent": "16678",
      "total_amount": "9764231",
      "date": 1450915200
  }, {
      "total_earned": "12546",
      "total_spent": "16164",
      "total_amount": "17758",
      "date": 1451001600
  }]
}
```

The problem is everytime i call `total_earned` or `total_cashback` function it always load to server. I know it always call `loadChartData` function and it run the server. I've tried to put the data to `$scope.data` but everytime I call it outside the function, the data is `undefined`.

Any solution so I can keep changing data based on type without loading it to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but you should store the result of the call to loadChartData in a variable, then you can access it whenever you want as a proimise. For example:

```
var data = loadChartData(type);
data.then(function(values) {
  // do something with values
});
```

The problem is you're returning a promise, not a value, and every time you call your loadChartData function you're fetching the result from the server and returning a new promise. You can simply reuse the original promise. If you don't know much about angular promises, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

You need to separate the data fetching call from the business logic, that way, you can fetch with one call, get all the appropriate data, and then use it in whatever way you wish where ever you wish, like so:

```
function loadChartData() {
    return Vendor.get({id: vendorId}).$promise;
});
var data = loadChartData();
data.then(function(data) {
  //do something with data
});
data.then(function(data) {
  //do something else with data
});
```

Comment: Hi. I will try your solution. To make it clear, I want to get the data and then I can use it dynamically. like change something and i can get the different result without querying again